# ServerConfig.getChannel() doesn't work despite compiling with services-config.xml

Tags: flash, blazeds, channel

I'm developing a pure AS3 application using BlazeDS for backend communication.
Currently I'm defining the AMFChannels at runtime using something like this:

`var amfChannel:AMFChannel = new AMFChannel("my-amf", "http://127.0.0.1:8400/foo/messagebroker/amf");`

Now I want to get rid of this hardcoded configuration.
As far as I understood, I just need to compile with *-service* option including *services-config.xml* and calling something like this at runtime:

```
var amfChannel:* = ServerConfig.getChannel("my-amf");
```

Of course I have a channel with *id="my-amf"* in *services-config.xml*, but I keep getting the  error message, that the channel is not valid.
Indeed the static *ServerConfig.xml* (which afaik should contain the XML object representing the *services-config.xml*) is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your services-config.xml?